# Moving Files by creation/modification date then moving with Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, module

I am new to programming, even more so with Python. So please excuse any ignorance on my part. I am trying to write a script for myself that will move files that have been modified in the last 24 hours. So far I have came up with this:

```
import datetime
import os
import shutil


src = "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderA"
dst = "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderB"


now = dt.datetime.now()
before = now - dt.timedelta(hours=24)

def mins_since_mod(fname):
    return (os.path.getmtime(fname))


for fname in os.listdir(src):
    if mins_since_mod > before:
        src_fname = os.path.join(src,fname)
        os.path.join(dst,fname)
        shutil.move(src_fname, dst)
```

I know i'm close to the solution, but I can't seem to figure out how to get this to work. I looked around here on the community and was not able to find a solution to my problem. Thank you for any leads or suggestions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are a few things to change. First, you can't compare the `datetime` in `before` to the Unix timestamp that `getmtime()` returns. It's easier to just use that directly. Also, you actually need to pass the (full) filename to `mins_since_mod()` for it to do anything.

Here's something that should work, changing the name of `mins_since_mod()` to reflect what it does better:

```
import time
import os
import shutil

SECONDS_IN_DAY = 24 * 60 * 60

src = "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderA"
dst = "C:\Users\Student\Desktop\FolderB"

now = time.time()
before = now - SECONDS_IN_DAY

def last_mod_time(fname):
    return os.path.getmtime(fname)

for fname in os.listdir(src):
    src_fname = os.path.join(src, fname)
    if last_mod_time(src_fname) > before:
        dst_fname = os.path.join(dst, fname)
        shutil.move(src_fname, dst_fname)
```

Comment: This worked perfectly, thank you for clarifying what you did as well. @CFNZ_Techie was awesome too, but this was closest to my own script written.

Answer (score 2):

Hey mate I have actually just done something like this myself.  I found that there will be a few issues will the time comparison as well as some issues in comparing and moving folders.

Try this:

```
import os
import shutil
import datetime

def filter_by_date(src_folder, archive_date):
    os.chdir(src_folder)
    delay_time = 24 * 60 * 60
    archive_period = archive_date - delay_time
    return [
        name for name in os.listdir(u'.')
        if os.path.isdir(name)
        and datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(name)) < archive_period
    ]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    folders = filter_by_date("C:/Users/Student/Desktop/FolderA", time.time())
    for files in folders:
        print files
        try:
            shutil.copytree(files, os.path.join("C:/Users/Student/Desktop/New", files))
        except OSError as e:
            print('\nDirectory not copied. Error: %s' % e)
        except shutil.Error as e:
            try:
                files = files.encode('UTF-8')
                dst_path = os.path.join('C:/Users/Student/Desktop/FolderB/', files)
                shutil.copytree(files, dst_path)
            finally:
                print('\nDirectory not copied. Error: %s' % e)

    print "\Completed"
```

This is going to ensure any file name (including Chinese, Russian and Japanese will be copied) and any folder (directory or sub-directory) is copied. It will also keep all file attributes.